# is there a way to change a Notification Center Icons?

Tags: notification-area

I would like to change the icon for one of my Windows Notification Center icons, it is in strong contrast to all of the others and a nuisance.

**Example**

[image]

**Question**

- How can I manually change this icon?

Comment: not easily, but with a great nuisance possibly

Comment: how does this nuisance work or look :)?? Give me a nudge in the right direction, I will then solve it and post my answer here :)!

Comment: using a Windows tool to edit the EXE you change the icon

Answer (score 1):

There is a program that I have used in the past called: Resource Hacker.

Though I have not specifically used it to change the notification icon, I have used it to change many icons throughout an application and would expect the notification bar icon to be available for customization.

Comment: I just downloaded Resource Hacker, eager to explore and to find a solution here. Any suggestions of where to look to solve this task, inside Resource Hacker :)?

Comment: @j-dizzle I haven't found any methods, the names under which the icons are under are not intuitive at all.  In some cases, there have been blog posts of people who found the exact location for whatever it is you're trying to do at the time, but for the most part I just go through everything until I find what I'm looking for.